# Angularjs : get value of scope variable in a controller defined inside another controller which is inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where a controller is defined and there is a variable say "`$scope.accesJson`". I need to access it from another controller.

**Code:**

```
angular.module('test.directives').directive("manageAccess", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "template/test.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $http) {
            $scope.accesJson = ["hi","hello"];
        }
    };
});
```

I have another controller,

```
angular.module("test.controllers").controller("testController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getUsers = function() {
        console.log $scope.accesJson //I need value of $scope.accesJson here.
    }
});
```

How can I do that?

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sharing data between different controller Service's are good option. Define one like so,

```
angular.module("test.services").factory('DataBasket', function () {
    return {};
});
```

And in the directive

```
controller: function($scope, $element, $http, DataBasket) {
        DataBasket.accessJson = ["hi", "hello"];
        $scope.accesJson = DataBasket.accessJson;
    }
```

from other controller

```
angular.module("test.controllers").controller("testController", function($scope, $http, DataBasket) {
    $scope.getUsers = function() {
        console.log DataBasket.accesJson 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To share resources across two controllers, you can always use a service or a factory. You may also do it by defining a global variable, but that is NOT encouraged.

To declare a factory:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
 .factory('appSvc',[function(){
  var resources = {};
   return resources;
 }]);
```

note that you can declare re-usable functions inside a factory.

With your factory declared, remember to inject it properly into your controllers who needs it.

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['appSvc',function(appSvc){
 //do something with your appSvc
 }]);
```

Here is a very [simple plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XSp5ltPrebarJg6L15cY?p=preview) to show how service/factory is used to get and set data.

For in-depth documentation: [AngularJs Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Answer (score 1):

You can also bind a property from the outer $scope to the directive in the linking function of the directive, like so:

```
angular.module('foo', [])

.directive("manageAccess",
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        property: '='
      },
      link: function($scope) {
        $scope.property = { foo: 1 }
      }
    }
  }
)

.controller('Main',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.showAccessJsonValue = function() {
      $scope.value = $scope.accessJson
    }
  }
)
```

Then in your template, you could have a `ng-click` that calls `showAccessJsonValue` which will give you the value that you assigned in the directive.

Like,

```
<body ng-controller="Main">

<manage-access property="accessJson"></manage-access>

<button ng-click="showAccessJsonValue()">Show value</button>

<pre>{{value | json}}</pre>

</body>
```

Here's a [demo Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hParYKDmUWEVw1wzZU7E?p=preview).